# Meaning of the idiom "To leave the friendship of men"

Tags: idiom-meaning

I found the saying in a 17th century [English-Dutch dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Large_Netherdutch_and_English_Dictiona/CjanmlTkXqMC?hl=en&gbpv=1),
[image]

Is there a figurative meaning to the phrase beyond the literal meaning of the words?

Comment: It's apparently an old Latin idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cicero uses a form of this expression in De Amicitia, and it appears that the use is literal: a separation from friends, the company of men, for whatever reason the writer has in mind. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take it literally. The idiom is Latin, but its English translation is not. It is simply a literal translation.

It may be an allusion to the Psalm:

> Trust not in princes, nor in the children of men, in whom there is no safety.
> (Ps. 146:3 LXE)